# Convert EditText text to uppercase and lowercase , when clicked on button?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

What i am trying to do is take input from the user and on button click event i want to display that `EditText` input on T`extView`. On button click listener, textView should display the input string in All caps and then clicking the same button it should convert that string into lowercase an show it on `TextView`. How can I achieve this?

This is what i have tried.

```
var userInput = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
var caseButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.upperLowerButton)
var caseView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textUpperLower)

caseButton.setOnClickListener {
    caseView.text =  userInput.text
}
```

Comment: Take a look into documentation. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase() and https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase()

Comment: caseView.text = userInput.text.toString().toUpperCase()/toLowerCase()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
val uppercase = userInput.text.toString().toUpperCase()
val lowerCase = uppercase.toLowerCase()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using methods - toUpperCase() and toLowerCase() can easily solve this problem.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String h =  textView.getText().toString();
                    if (isCaps) {
                        textView.setText(h.toUpperCase());
                        isCaps = false;
                    }
                       else {
                           textView.setText(h.toLowerCase());
                       isCaps = true;}
                    }
    
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toUpperCase()` and `.toLowerCase()` for your string values e.g.

```
userInput.text.toString().toUpperCase()
```

and

```
userInput.text.toString().toLowerCase()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like following.

```
var isUpperCase = false;
var txt = userInput.text.toString()
caseButton.setOnClickListener {
      if(isUpperCase){
         txt = txt.toLowerCase()
         isUpperCase = false
      }else{
          txt = txt.toUpperCase()
          isUpperCase = true
      }
       caseView.text =  txt
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin as `toUperCase()` and `toLowerCase()` are deprecated we can use `uppercase()` instead of `toUpperCase()` and `lowercase()` instead of `toLowerCase()`.

For example,

```
val lower="abc"
Log.e("TAG", "Uppercase: ${lower.uppercase()}" ) //ABC
val upper="ABC"
Log.e("TAG", "Lowercase: ${upper.lowercase()}" ) //abc
```